# Optimising woocommerce to be aligned on mobile

Tags: woocommerce

I've installed WooCommence into my theme but when it goes to the mobile version the Shop section doesn't stay inline with the theme. It looks fine on desktop.

http://twosixwellness.com.au/shop/

If anyone has seen this issue before and has a solution please let me know.

Thanks for your assistance.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

all you need to to is to select a responsive theme, there are a lot of nice themes for free in wordpress. Woocommerce depends on the theme you choose. Most of the themes are woocommerce friendly but make sure you choose a **responsive** theme.

Comment: Hi @csandreas1, yes the website users the Mokka blog theme which is responsive, however, the developers of the theme have said it's not WooCommerce compatible. The site owners want to sell a product so that's why I'm trying to get it to work and why the alignment is not right. I need padding added to the sides so it's not touching the edges.